# Uniform Continuity of a function with the simplest way

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, uniform-continuity

I'm trying to show that

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x \sin\left(\frac1x\right),\quad\text{if $x \in (0,1]$ }\\[2ex]
0, \quad \quad \quad \quad \ \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}$

is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ and let $x, y \in (0,1)$.
Then
$$
 \left|x\sin\frac{1}{x} - y \sin\frac{1}{y} \right|=\left| x\sin\frac{1}{x} - y\sin\frac{1}{x} + y\sin\frac{1}{x} - y \sin\frac{1}{y} \right|
= \left| (x-y)\sin\frac{1}{x} + y \left(\sin\frac{1}{x} - \sin\frac1y\right) \right| $$
and by triangle inequality
\begin{equation}
\label{eq: star}
\left | x\sin\frac{1}{x} - y \sin\frac{1}{y} \right |
\leq |x - y| + y \left | \sin\frac{1}{x} - \sin\frac{1}{y} \right |
\end{equation}
$$\left |  \sin\frac{1}{x} -\sin\frac{1}{y} \right|= \left | 2 \cos \left ( \frac{1}{2} \left ( \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} \right ) \right ) \sin \left ( \frac{1}{2} \left ( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y} \right ) \right ) \right |$$

I could not continue from there. Is there any basic way for this? I've seen other answers on this question but I'm looking for really simple one for **formal proof**.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Isn't enough to say that it is a continuous function on a compact set, thus it is uniformly continuous?

Comment: The comment by @Crostul is the simplest way.

Comment: @Crostul I know it. I meant simplest way for formal proof

Comment: It *is* way simpler to show that any continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous than it is to explicitly parry $\varepsilon$ for the above function. So even if you would have to also give that proof, you're saving time.

Comment: The simplest way is to read the formal proof of the general theorem that a continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous. If you like, you can rewrite the proof by substituting your function into it.

Comment: The theorem that others are mentioning is called the [Heine-Cantor Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine–Cantor_theorem).

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks a lot for all comments. I know that theorem also I’ve proved it too. I only wondered its formal proof

Comment: You keep saying "formal proof". I think you might mean "elementary proof".

Comment: @zhw. No. Proof with formal definition of uniform continuity i.e. epsilon-delta definition of uniform continuity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an ad-hoc proof. Let $\epsilon>0$ be fixed. We can and do adjust it to $1$ if it is bigger.

The function $|f'|$ is bounded and continuous on $[\epsilon/3, \; 1]$, let $M> 3$ be an upper bound.
We set $\delta = \epsilon/M<\epsilon/3$.

Let $x,y$ be two points in $[0,1]$ at distance $<\delta$, and we can and do assume $0\le x\le y\le x+\delta$. Two cases:

- If $x$ is in the interval $[0,\epsilon/3]$ then we have:

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le |f(x)|+|f(y)|\le x+y\le 2x+(y-x)<
\frac 23\epsilon +\delta<\epsilon\ .
$$

- If $x>\epsilon/3$ then both $x,y$ live in the interval $[\epsilon/3,\; 1]$ where we can find an intermediate point $\xi$ with

$$|f(x)-f(y)|=|f'(\xi)|\;|x-y|<M|x-y|<M\delta<\epsilon\ .
$$